# Can I use UIPerformance grails plugin and host my static resources in another domain?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, static-resource

The [**UIPerfomance**](http://www.grails.org/plugin/ui-performance) plugin is an easy way to speed up your web pages by applying some of the [best practices rules](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) from Yahoo performance team (like minifying, setting a far-future expires header, versioned images...)

Unfortunately I didn't find a way to store the static resources in a location **outside of the webapplication** which has his own advantages ( smaller WAR sizes, better optimize cookieless server, static resources served faster by a highly optimized native httpd, no need to redeploy WAR when updating static resources..).

So my question is:

is it possible to use this great plugin with static resoures stored outside the web application? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that a JIRA issue was raised for this (see [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1606))

Thanks to Oliver Weichhold, there is also a patch that allows combining UIPerformance plugin with another dedicated domain for static resources